# Spacy dependency parse: negative rules

Tags: python, spacy

I'm using the dependency parser to see if a sentence matches a rule with exceptions. For example, I'm trying to find all sentences whose noun subject does not have a complement word (adjective, compound, etc.).

A positive case is.

```
The school is built in 1978.
```

A negative case is.

```
The Blue Sky Airline is 70 years old.
```

My current Spacy pattern matches all two cases.

```py
[
    {"RIGHT_ID": "copula", "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"LEMMA": "be"}},
    # subject of the verb
    {
        "LEFT_ID": "copula",
        "REL_OP": ">",
        "RIGHT_ID": "subject",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"DEP": "nsubj"},
    },
]
```

Is there a negative `REL_OP`? I want to exclude some relations between tokens.

Answer (score 0):

There is no negative `REL_OP`.

I haven't seen this come up before... It's a little weird, but your best option might be to match the complements you want to exclude, and keep any sentence with no matches.